# Can parent containers width expand to child's scaled content size?

Tags: css, width, scale, scaletransform

I have a fundamental question about if scaled elements can affect their container's dimensions and how to do that.

The issue I'm having is on this floating label [Codepen](https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/JzNxPK?editors=1100) I made. When the label is floated it is transformed into place and scaled down.

However, its container stays the same size causing to much of a gap.

Here is the markup from the pen:

```
<div class="floating-label active">
  <input class="floating-label__input" type="text" name="firstName" autocomplete="off" required placeholder=" "/>
      <div class="floating-label__outline">
        <div class="floating-label__leading"></div>

        <div class="floating-label__notch">
          <label class="floating-label__label" for="firstName">Label long text</label>
        </div>

        <div class="floating-label__trailing"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`.floating-label__notch` is the container for the floating label. It does not shrink its width when the label is scaled down.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way a scaled element can impact its container. That would involve performance heavy resizing and recalculations of all related elements, which transitions are trying to mitigate. By not impacting surrounding elements transitions have a huge performance advantage over scaling width, height etc.

If you want to scale something and let its size impact other elements, you have to scale font-size, height or width. Though it goes without saying that it's more performance heavy.